# Elasticsearch + Nest: Errors are ignored in MultiGetRequests

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

In an application I'm querying for 2 documents by Id ("doc1" and "doc2") using an index alias "my_alias"

```
var multiGetRequest = new MultiGetRequest
{
    Documents = new [] { 
        new MultiGetOperation<Product>("doc1") {Index = "my_alias" },
        new MultiGetOperation<Product>("doc2") {Index = "my_alias" }
    }

};

var result = client.MultiGet(multiGetRequest);
if (!response.IsValid){
  throw new Exception();
}

var documents = result.Documents;
```

All is fine until someone messes with the alias in Elasticsearch and addes a second index to the alias. The new index also contains documents with ids "doc1" and "doc2".

Using the MultiGet now will lead to

```
Alias [,y_alias] has more than one indices associated 
with it [[demo_index, demo_index2]], can't execute a single index op"
```

This a expected - but how do I catch the error when using the MultiGet operation?

The code above still executes with out any errors, but now it return **no results**

Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: I believe you can grab it from `multiGetRequest.ServerError`.

Comment: `IsValid` is still `true`? What version of NEST? What version of Elasticsearch?

Comment: yes, IsValid is true. Version 5.5.0

Comment: @Rob - ServerError is null :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in NEST.

Currently the client doesn't deserialize the `error` property on items in the `docs` array and additionally, does not take these into account when determining whether the response is valid. [I've opened an issue to address this.](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/2871)